# Отслеживание изменений в редактируемом элементе

Tags: html, css

У меня есть элемент, который `contentEditable`. У него есть дети, в которых есть обработчики событий, которые могут предотвратить обработку ввода текста. С помощью какого события я могу понять, что произвелось изменение именно в `contentEditable`-элементе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно будет событие onchange